# Why -f flag of ssh-keygen fails to follow symlink?

Tags: bash, ssh, environment-variables, zsh, ssh-keygen

My `~/.ssh` directory is a symlink to `/somewhere/else/.ssh/`

Now, the following works perfectly; and the *demo* key ends up getting created at `/somewhere/else/.ssh/Official`, as expected.

```
export NewUser="Sam"
ssh-keygen -N "" -t rsa -b 8192 -C "Login Key of ${NewUser}." -f ~/.ssh/Official/demo
```

However, when `-f` is supplied with the same path but via a variable, it fails with the following error:
`Saving key "~/.ssh/Official/demo" failed: No such file or directory`

```
export NewUser="Darsh"
export SSHKey_Path="~/.ssh/Official/demo"
ssh-keygen -N "" -t rsa -b 8192 -C "Login Key of ${NewUser}." -f ${SSHKey_Path}
```

I have tried several ways to supply this variable, but nothing worked. I'm not able to find anything about variables in the documentation either. **I wish to know why does `-f` fail to follow the symlink path ONLY if passed via a variable? Is there a workaround?** I'm not sure but, would it be recommended to bring this to notice [here](https://www.openssh.com/report.html)?

---

---

### *EDIT: Updating question after debugging. The original question has been preserved below*:

I am aware that `ssh-keygen` has a flag `-f` to specify `input_keyfile` - With which, once can create a key with custom name at a custom location. However, this fails if the `input_keyfile` is a variable. 
**How do I provide the key path as a variable to ssh-keygen?**

Following are oversimplified snippets from the bigger code:
This works perfectly:

```
export NewUser="Sam"
ssh-keygen -N "" -t rsa -b 8192 -C "Login Key of ${NewUser}." -f ~/.ssh/Official/demo
```

However, this fails with the following error **Saving key "~/.ssh/Official/demo" failed: No such file or directory**

```
export NewUser="Darsh"
export SSHKey_Path="~/.ssh/Official/demo"
ssh-keygen -N "" -t rsa -b 8192 -C "Login Key of ${NewUser}." -f ${SSHKey_Path}
```

I have tried wrapping ${SSHKey_Path} in several ways, but nothing worked:
`"`, `'`, `$(echo ${SSHKey_Path})`, and many more.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The failure is not in the variable, but in the interpretation of `~`.

Try

```
export SSHKey_Path=~/.ssh/Official/demo
```

or

```
export SSHKey_Path="$HOME/.ssh/Official/demo"
```

Comment: Yes, I did try with these as well. As long as there's a variable in the -f, it fails to work.

Comment: I have investigated further on my problem. Turns out the issue is with regard to symlinks actually. I have updated the question.

Comment: When you tried the two solutions I gave, what error messages did you get ?